# Install cygwin under windows 10 and compile openjdk8

Tags: java

Install cygwin3.2.0 under windows 10 and compile openjdk8.
Compilation ended successfully

but
I found that the memory usage increased and could not be released. Unless I restart windows. After restarting windows, about 4Gb of memory was released. Every time the JDK is compiled, the memory rises sharply. Excuse me, can anyone help me answer? Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to *compile* a jdk, as opposed to using one?

Comment: What does task manager show?